# vue component html elemnet Rendering

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am developing a multi-page web application (MPA) using Laravel version 5.6 with vue.js version 2.0.

I am using multiple vue components e.g. Demo.vue and using that component in php blade file.

The issue is when I try to see the page view source (ctrl+u) it shows only html tags used in php blade file but doesn't show vue component's HTML elements.

I want the Vue component HTML elements also to be shown in page view source since my google crawling is majorly dependent on vue components used. Could you help me out for this issue?

Also attaching the screenshots of the page source and example code snippet for the same.

- Demo.vue file code

  ```
  <template>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="card card-default">
                          <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                          <div class="card-body">
                              I'm an example component.
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </template>

  <script>
      export default {
          mounted() {
              console.log('Component mounted.')
          }
      }
  </script>
  ```
- App.js

  ```
  require('./bootstrap');
  window.Vue = require('vue');
  window.axios = require('axios');
  import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';

  Vue.use(VModal);
  Vue.component('demo-component', require('./components/Demo.vue'));
  const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',

  });
  ```
- Layout.blade.php

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">

      <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                  <form method="POST" action="path_to_action">
                  <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                  </form>
            <!--<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
                   <link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body id="body">

          <div class="content" id="app">
           <demo-component></demo-component>
          </div>



          <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>


      </body>
  </html>
  ```

i.e. We want the HTML code of  to be rendered in view source.

We even tried to check various articles on SSR, but those examples are shown using static content, whereas our data is dynamic coming from database and is a multi-page application.

e.g. We tried below approach :-

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/11/06/vue-js-laravel-server-side-rendering/

The above article is showing for static data only...

Thanks,
Charlize

Comment: Did you transpile the `App.js` file ? Are there any errors in your browser console ?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve this? Are there any benefits to show the rendered HTML in the view-source?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem that you face by choosing to use a reactive framework like Vue. The problem is that the HTML itself is not rendered at the time of initial page load, but populated by javascript after the fact and then rendered to the user. You can not get around this particular problem with Vue components and since you are using dynamic data, you can not cache the HTML itself.

However, an interesting approach that I have used successfully in the past is to actually render "placeholder" HTML on page load that simply omits the dynamic data, and then use the v-show or v-if method to toggle the placeholder HTML and the dynamic HTML data once the data finishes loading. If you don't use transitions, this can lead to some flashing, but if you REALLY want to have google crawl that HTML, and you really need to use Vue, then this is a good solution. A simplified example would be something like this:

```
<div v-show="loaded">
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>
<div id="placeholder">
    <div>
        Hello, Google Bot!
    </div>
</div>
```

You would then change the value of the "loaded" variable to true when your component is mounted and pass it to the parent with an emitter, while also using javascript to hide the original div, thus replacing the placeholder HTML with your Vue generated HTML. Google would be able to see whatever was in the placeholder, and you still get the dynamic content once it loads. This is not the prettiest of answers, and requires using some very non-reactive practices to achieve the result, but please note that it's just an attempt to give you an answer that might work for your particular use case.

While implementing this method, you may want to consider using includes within the Vue component itself that actually call the placeholder HTML so that you don't repeat yourself, and you are only updating the static HTML in one source location. I can give more help with this if you require it.

Comment: **consider using includes within the Vue component itself that actually call the placeholder HTML**  I am not getting (ACTUALLY HOW TO IMPLEMENT ABOVE SENTENCE)what you want to say .can you explain it deeply ?

Comment: That’s the least important part of my answer, just reminding you to use DRY principles and reuse code where you can.

Comment: what I dont get is how a component is a self-contained chunk of JS but vueJS cant just say, oh there an X tag replace it with an instance of X component. Would make adopting Vue so dam easy if I could just use existing components anywhere in the DOM without rebuilding the entire pace in VueJS